# Как TooltipCompat отобразить при нажатии?

Tags: android, tooltip

У меня есть задача в моём приложении чтобы сделать кнопку и рядом с ней значок "Вопроса" и при нажатии на неё должно отображатся всплывающее окно. Немного поискав информации я решил остановится на варианте с TooltipCompat и он у меня работает, но есть одна проблема он работает только при удержании на кнопку. Как мне отобразить подсказку без долгого нажатия, а просто при клике? Делаю его через код т. к. у меня приложение начинается с API 20.

Comment: Возможно вам нужен Toast?

Comment: Нет про существования Toast'a  я знаю, но мне нужно именно TooltipCompat или хорошая альтернатива (не Toast просто у меня эта кнопка находится в ScrollView и она может находится не в статичном состоянии)

Comment: Судя по описанию из доки оно будет работать в т.ч. по длинному нажатию. Если вам такое подходит - можете покопаться в исходниках на предмет программного вызова функционала по обычному нажатию либо по обычному нажатию программно вызывать колбэк длинного нажатия.